# como ver la version de windows

Tags: windows-forms, windows, cmd, permisos

quiero ver que versión de windows es la imagen iso que tengo (profesional,pro etc) ingreso este comando dism /Get-WimInfo /WimFile:F:\sources\install.esd /index:1 pero me da este error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

cabe resaltar que si tengo permisos de admin, y la imagen esta en la partición f
agradecería su ayuda.

Comment: Puedes acceder a la particion F, desde cmd ?

Answer (score -1):

El error que te da es por la ruta del archivo install.esd.

- Asegúrate de la extensión del archivo, install.**esd** o install.**wim**
- Comprueba que la ruta del archivo install.esd o install.wim sea correcta.
- La imagen iso debe de estar montada en un USB booteable o CD.

Este [link](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/iso-find-windows-build-version-edition-using-dism/) te lo explica bien, aunque seguro que ya lo habrás mirado.

Comment: El problema consiste en que no puede acceder a la particion F desde su CMD